# Why does my very simple Chrome extension work on Mac but not PC?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, google-chrome-extension

I have written a *very* simple Chrome extension. It consists of this background page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

chrome.tabs.onDetached.addListener(function(tabId, info){
    var id = tabId;
    chrome.tabs.get(id, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            windowId : info.oldWindowId, 
            index : info.oldPosition, 
            url : tab.url
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

All it does is allows you to pull a tab from a window without losing that tab and web address from the window. It basically duplicates the tab when you detach it.

The problem is that this works perfectly on a Mac but when I have tried it on two different Windows machines I get this error

```
background.html:7Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

It appears the tab object isn't being passed into the `get` callback. Does anyone know why this might be? It obviously is when I run the code on a Mac.

Comment: It does seem strange. I tried this in one my extensions and saw same behavior. It is like the current tab is destroyed immediately after detach on windows. But then must be recreated on drop because the id stays the same. Or .get() just doesn't work for tabs in a drag state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is tab id changes after it is detached (old one doesn't exist anymore). Not sure whether it is an error or feature, but if it is inconsistent between Mac and PC then it is definitely an error (could be just performance difference - api method executes faster than tab detaches on a different computer).

*mrtsherman* was on right track with workaround, only instead of saving `id` you should save `info` as that `id` doesn't mean anything anymore. Then you would have all information to recreate a tab (use attached `info` to get tab id, and saved detached `info` to get old position and window).

Comment: in my experiments i actually saw that the id persisted. So before detach id is `123`, while window is in drag mode it is inacessible, finally after drop in new window id is again `123` Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Do you think if I added a `setTimeout` it would do the trick then?

Comment: @MrMisterMan It would do the trick of not working on mac either.

Comment: @serg I see. That wasn't the trick I was looking for. I'm away from my computer now but I'll have another look at this tomorrow. Thank you both for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the only workaround that I can think of:

1. OnDetached - store id of tab and also its window id
2. OnAttached - check whether tab id matches stored tab id AND that window id is now different. If so then create new tab in the old window.

Behavior does seem wonky. Perhaps file a bug report?